# "qimage out of memory returning null image" after working for 60 QImages

Tags: qt, opencv, qimage, qpixmap

I read a lot of posts on this topic but no post seems to help me.
I am running a 32Bit Qt Application.

I wonder why I receive this error at some point:

> qimage out of memory returning null image

I want to read videoframes from a mp4 File and convert them into a QImage. After that, I want to convert the QImage to a QPixmap to display it on a QGraphicsView (setPixmap).

That's the relevant code:

Function I use to convert a cv::Mat into a QPixmap:

```
QPixmap QtMainApp::MatToQPixmap(cv::Mat& cvMat)
{
    QImage qimg((cvMat).data,
        (cvMat).cols,
        (cvMat).rows,
        (cvMat).step,
        QImage::Format_RGB888);

    return QPixmap::fromImage(qimg.rgbSwapped());
}
```

Where I call the function and read the video frames from the mp4 file:

```
std::vector <QPixmap> vecQVideobilder{};
 
cv::VideoCapture videofile;
videofile.open("video.mp4");

while(true)
{

   bool bErfolg = videofile.read(MatTemp);
                
   if (!bErfolg)
       break;

              
   vecQVideobilder.push_back(MatToQPixmap(MatTemp));
                

}
```

The weird thing is, that it works fine for a random number of frames. I can display these frames without a problem.

But at some point (after 60 to 100 frames (it differs)) I receive the error message and I get blank images only.

I have read that It could be that the size/solution of the frame is too big for a 32Bit application QImage. But then I wonder why it is working for the first 60 or 100 frames.

Is there something I can do? Thanks in advance.

Kind regards
Tim

Comment: How big is one of your images? Then calculate the size. When it's 1280x1024 then every image needs 5MB, 100Images -> you need 500MB of free memory. For 1920x1080 you already need ~830MB

Comment: Monitor the amount of RAM your application is using. 32 bit application could theoretically use a maximum of 4GB ram.